# What does Recommend deletion button do in the Low Quality Review Queue ?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

What does the `Recommend Deletion` do in the low quality review queue ?

Who does it recommend deletion to ?

Do a sufficient number of recommended deletion votes auto delete the post ?

Comment: And 6 recommend deletion votes will delete the post.

Answer (score 4):

Recommend Deletion to recommend that this answer be deleted

If we select recommend deletion, it bumps the post higher in the queue for trusted  users who have the power to vote for deletion.